# Java "Unreachable Code" Errors

Tags: java

I am currently using Eclipse to code a new plugin. I have been following tutorials online, however have ran into an error. My friend has been helping with the code, however he is unsure of this fix. I am running into an "Unreachable code" error. I have marked the location of the error. Thanks for any help!

http://pastebin.com/tpeFWsas

Comment: `if(com.equalsIgnoreCase("tele")); {`? What is the reason to have a `;` there?

Comment: oops, a wayward, semicolon. Legacy: please post your code related to your question here in the forum.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  Actually, now that I think about it, the site the the OP linked shows a much more appealing layout of code than SO does, and i think there's some benefits to not posting it in the op, makes the OP less ugly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't put a semicolon at the end of your if statement.  as the commenter mentioned, you've made this mistake on line 33, 50, and 66

Also, for the sake of readability, make sure that your code blocks line  up.  a few lines above your error you will see 2 `}` in the same column.  stuff like that makes the code hard to read.

Comment: at least two other times the same mistake

Comment: Note to OP:  You've done this on lines 33, 50, and 66.  You'll want to fix all three.

Comment: Thank you very much! It fixed my problem. Thanks for the tips with the {'s too!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(com.equalsIgnoreCase("ext"));
```

> semicolon

closes your method there and code after that is not valid.

should be

```
 if(com.equalsIgnoreCase("ext")) {
```